# ASP.NET MVC not finding/using custom type editor template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, templates, mvc-editor-templates, editorformodel

I'm stuck trying to figure out why my template is not being rendered or found (as breakpoints on template are not being hit). I've got a model like this:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public Dropdown Cities { get; set; }
}
```

used in this view

```
@model Mvc.Models.SomeNamespace.SomeModel
@{
    Layout = "../Shared/_Site.cshtml";
}

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()

    <input type="submit" value="Continue">
}
```

where the Dropdown object definition is

```
public class Dropdown
{
    public int SelectedValue { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Values { get; set; }

    public string Placeholder { get; set; }
}
```

I've created an editor template for Dropdown under Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Dropdown.cshtml

```
@model Mvc.ViewModels.Dropdown

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedValue, Model.Values, Model.Placeholder)
```

The shocking thing for me is that I also have DateTime.cshtml template under that path that works just fine.

Every property on the model except for those of Dropdown type are being rendered, even the DateTime ones with its custom template.

Am I unaware of something?

**EDIT:** Already tried using [UIHint("Dropdown")] at Cities property.

**EDIT2:** Tried renaming to DropdownViewModel

Comment: Not related, but all it needs to be is `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedValue, Model.Values, Model.Placeholder)` - no need to create a 2nd identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, every shortcut is appreciated :)

Comment: Related: [Reusable editor template with DropDownList for business objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6744432/181087)

Comment: @NightOwl888 Already tried using UIHint to force to use the template without results

Comment: Try changing the name of your class. `Dropdown` is likely a reserved word because there is already a class in the MVC framework named `Dropdown`.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Tried changing everything with "DropdownViewModel" with no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default templates do not recurse down into nested complex objects. If you want this to happen you could always override this default behavior by creating a `~/Shared/EditorTemplates/Object.cshtml` with the following contents:

```
@if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1) 
{
    @ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText
} 
else 
{
    foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForEdit && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm))) 
    {
        if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml)
        {
            @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)
        }
        else
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Html.Label(prop.PropertyName).ToHtmlString()))
            {
                <div class="editor-label">@Html.Label(prop.PropertyName)</div>
            }
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)
                @Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName, "*")
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about the default templates in ASP.NET MVC in [this blog post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html).

Comment: Works like a charm, didn't know it doesn't support nested complex objects by default.

Comment: Unrelated note, as my example works with ValidationSummary enabled, it is preferable using @Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName) instead of adding the second "*" parameter to let the data annotations work properly

Comment: Hi Darin, SimpleDisplayText Not yet added to .Net Core 2! Would you please update your answer?

Comment: And also ToHtmlString.